# Passing data from dynamic tableview back to static tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Please help i have been struggling passing back the data. I have 2 tableViews. 1st tableview=static table=RootVC. 2nd tableview=dynamic table=FirstVC. in RootVC i have a cell with two labels, "repeatLabel" and "repeatDetail" with a disclosure indicator. When i click on the cell it display the next table which is FirstVC, FistVC is populated with weekdays. after selection of my choice, i want the selected days to be passed back into RootVC in "repeatDetail" and when i go back still be able to see previously selected data.

My RootVC looks like this:

```
    #import "RepeatViewController.h"
    @interface SettingsViewController : UITableViewController
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *repeatDetail;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *repeatLabel;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *getRepeatDetail;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *selectedDaysArray;
    @end


    in my RootVC.m
    #import "SettingsViewController.h"

    @interface SettingsViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation SettingsViewController
    @synthesize repeatLabel,repeatDetail;
    @synthesize getRepeatLabel;
    @synthesize selectedDaysArray;
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        repeatLabel.text = @"Repeat";
        repeatDetail.text = getRepeatLabel;



    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



     - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        RepeatViewController *destinationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        if( [destinationController isKindOfClass:[RepeatViewController class]] )
        {
            //You can reuse your selectedDays arrays
            destinationController.selectedDays = self.selectedDaysArray;
            [(RepeatViewController *)destinationController setCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *retDaysArray) // <- make this change
             {


                 // Save your changes
                 self.selectedDaysArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: retDaysArray]; // <- make this change

                 NSLog(@"retDaysArray: %@", self.selectedDaysArray); //<- Add this debug line
             }];
        }
    }


    @end

    My 1stVC.h

    #import "SettingsViewController.h"
    typedef void(^WeekdayCompletionBlock)(NSArray *retDaysArray);
    @interface RepeatViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

    @property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *selectedDays;
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *completionBlock;
    @property (copy) WeekdayCompletionBlock returnBlock;
    //@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveButton;
    -(IBAction)save:(id)sender;
    @end

    my 1stVC.m

    #import "RepeatViewController.h"

    @interface RepeatViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation RepeatViewController
    @synthesize selectedDays= _selectedDays;
    @synthesize completionBlock;
    @synthesize returnBlock;
    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        completionBlock = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sunday", @"Monday", @"Tuesday", @"Wednesday", @"Thursday", @"Friday", @"Saturday", nil];


    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return 7;
    }



     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"RepeatCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


        }
        NSString *day = completionBlock[indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = day;
        if ([self.selectedDays containsObject:day])
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        else
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;


        //cell.textLabel.text = [completionBlock objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view delegate


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (!self.selectedDays)
            self.selectedDays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            //remove data from array
            [self.selectedDays removeObject:[completionBlock objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            //add data to array
            [self.selectedDays addObject:[completionBlock objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        }

        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }


    -(IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *myNewWeekString = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [myNewWeekString setObject:self.selectedDays forKey:@"MY_KEY_FOR_ACCESING_DAYSOFWEEK"];
    [myNewWeekString synchronize];

    //NSLog(@"The selected day/s is %@",self.selectedDays);

    if (self.returnBlock)
    {
        self.returnBlock(self.selectedDays);
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   // NSLog(@"The selected day/s is %@",self.selectedDays);
   // if (self.returnBlock)
   // {
      //  self.returnBlock([completionBlock objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    //}

}



      /*
    -(void) setReturnBlock:(WeekdayCompletionBlock)returnBlock
    {
        [self.selectedDays addObject:(self.returnArray);
    }

    - (NSArray *)setDats
    {
        return [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.selectedDays copy]];
    }*/




    @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you work with static cells you have to bind the control you are using directly, there's no need.

So what I can suggest you is the following:

1. Bind your controls with some specific identifier, like labelFieldRow{rowid} example: labelFieldRow1.
2. So on prepare for segue, just check what's the selected row and pass the data you want to the destination controller.

Probably not the best, but it should work.

Comment: Hi Camilo, i'm new in IOS how can i do that, and what is the best way of doing it?

Comment: Do you know how to binds controls from the storyboard to your controller class?

Comment: sorry I was asking a question , how can i do that? I'm still new trying to understand tableviews. ANswer=NO i do not know how.

Comment: I post the answer. Let me know is it fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass data (selected by user before) from your RootVC to FirstVC. To do that in your RootVC add property to keep the selected data;

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *selectedDaysArray;
```

In prepareForSegue method you have to pass that array to let the table view know what needs to be selected:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        UIViewController *destinationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        if( [destinationController isKindOfClass:[RepeatViewController class]] )
        {
            //You can reuse your selectedDays arrays
             ((RepeatViewController*)destinationController).selectedDays = self.selectedDaysArray;
            [(RepeatViewController *)destinationController setReturnBlock:^(NSArray *retDaysArray) // <- make this change
             {
                 // Save your changes
                 self.selectedDaysArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: retDaysArray]; // <- make this change
                 NSLog(@"DATA: %@", self.selectedDaysArray) //<- Add this debug line
             }];
        }
    }
```

Remove this line from viewDidLoad you don't want to allocate it every time now you just pass it from rootVC

```
_selectedDays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

And in cellForRowInIndexPath replace this line:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [completionBlock objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

with this code:

```
    NSString *day = completionBlock[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = day;
    if ([self.selectedDays containsObject:day])
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

And change didSelectRowAtIndexPath: to

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!self.selectedDays)
        self.selectedDays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        //remove data from array
        [self.selectedDays removeObject:[completionBlock objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        //add data to array
        [self.selectedDays addObject:[completionBlock objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi Greg, it is still not working. No data is passed to RootVC.

Comment: I added debug line in the post can you add it and see can you see output in the console? Does the selection works (is it remember selected days)?

Comment: didn't know , i have posted above what i have. No data is being passed to RootVC

Comment: Have a look on this line [(RepeatViewController *)destinationController setReturnBlock: I changed it from [(RepeatViewController *)destinationController setCompletionBlock:. Let me know if you have any more issue.

Comment: If I have "UIViewController" i get an error -property 'selectedDays' not found in object of type'UIViewController'

Comment: destinationController.selectedDays = self.selectedDaysArray;
this line retutns property 'selectedDays' not found in object of type'UIViewController'

Comment: Unfortunately still no data is passed. But the previously selected data is still selected when i go back to FirstVC.Thank you so much for your help.